# No suitable driver found for jdbc.sqlite

Tags: java, sql

so firstly I have seen this question asked before - I looked at previous answers and tried to use that to sort my issue, however I couldn't.

I am creating a library system and have written the code for both the register class and login class, as well as creating a class for the database.  When I try and run the program, I am getting a message saying that there is no suitable driver found, followed by the file path for the database.  This is my database class:

```
    import java.sql.*;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;



   public class javaConnect {
   Connection conn;

public static Connection ConnecrDB() {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc.sqlite:process_f/Users/conorcurtis/Desktop/UNI/GCU IP Library/LibraryProject.sqliteiles");
        return conn;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        return null;
    }
```

I have absolutely no idea where to go with this so any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you add the sqlite jar in the library?

Comment: I thought I had, but looks like I hadn't! Thank you. However, it is now giving me a new error which is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC

Comment: If you are using Eclipse, go Project->Porperties->Java Build Path->Libraries->>Add Extenal Jars. After this add your sqlite jar.

Comment: I'm actually using netbeans, but I imagine I can do something similar?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: you can look here for netbeans: [Sqlite tutorial](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-java/sqlite-jdbc-driver/)

Answer (score 1):

What is probably happening here is that your driver is not in your classpath.  Your current problem is that you are dynamically loading the driver but it is not found.

You can turn this into a compile time error while debugging by adding to the import directives:

```
import org.sqlite.JDBC;
```

The difference is that the import directive is a compile-time dependency while the Class.forName call establishes a run-time dependency.  Usually we do this so we can change which databases are used without recompiling (but here you have your connection string hardwired so there is no point to doing it dynamically).  For example we could allow the connection string to be configured, and then load the appropriate driver dynamically.

So for now, add that import line and troubleshoot why the class is not found.  Chances are you have a build or class path problem.  If you are using maven, for example, you would want to add it there.

Once it compiles, you can remove the import directive and turn the error back into a run-time error.

But the basic checklist is:

1. Is the library available?
2. Is it in a path that is searched?
3. Do you have automatic dependency management tools (like maven) that are missing it as a dependency?