# No suitable JDBC Driver found

Tags: jdbc

I am making a library management system in java. When i run my code, it says that no suitable driver found for JDBC.sqlite. Same question is available here: [No suitable driver found for jdbc.sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42889281/no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbc-sqlite) but i could not find the suitable solution of my problem. I am using add-on (Sqlite manager) in firefox to create database file.
I have added the JDBC jar file.

 I have installed its driver but its not compatible.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.*;
import org.sqlite.JDBC;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class javaconnect {
    Connection conn;

    public static Connection ConnecrDB(){
        try{
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc.sqlite:E:\\Studies\\2nd Semester\\Java\\Library Management System\\LibraryNew.sqlite");
            return conn;
        }catch (Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            return null;
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Did you read the answer in your linked question above?  Most likely, the JVM just can't find the SQLite JDBC driver on the classpath.  So, you should tell us how you are setting up your build.

Comment: I have installed a few plugins of sqlite but its still not working

Comment: This isn't helping much.  You should review documentation which teaches you how to setup and build a Java project.  Your problem is probably more general than just a JDBC issue.

Comment: You have a typo in your url. It should start with `jdbc:sqlite:`, not `jdbc.sqlite:` (the separator is a colon (`:`), not a dot (`.`)).

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel thank u so much. Its working